# Laravel: How to test cookies inside a listener?

Tags: laravel, cookies

I'm trying to add a listener to the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered`-event.

The listener is quite simple:

```
/**
 * Called when user is registered
 */
class SetAffiliate
{
    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        // check if the cookie exists and if so, save it to the user
        if (request()->cookie('affiliate') && Affiliate::find(request()->cookie('affiliate'))) {
            $event->user->affiliate_id = request()->cookie('affiliate');
            $event->user->save();
        }
    }
}
```

How would you test for this?

This is my current test:

```
/** @test */
public function it_sets_the_correct_affiliate_id_into_the_new_registered_user()
{
    // Create affiliate + the user
    $affiliate = Affiliate::factory()->create();

    // Create a brand new user
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    // Setting the cookie
    $this->get($affiliate->referralLink)
         ->assertCookie('affiliate', $affiliate->id); //it works

    $this->assertNull($user->affiliate_id);

    (new SetAffiliate())->handle(
        new Registered($user)
    );

    $this->assertNotNull($user->fresh()->affiliate_id);
}
```

It still fails at the last line of code:

> Failed asserting that null is not null.

Any idea how I can add the cookie to the listener?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same requests.

When you use $this->get() - another instance of Laravel created behind the scene - with their own Request

You must send this event directly in code which calls in $affiliate->referralLink, not in TestCase.

Anyway, your test is not good - it's feature test and he know too many about application.

```
// Create affiliate + the user
$affiliate = Affiliate::factory()->create();

// Create a brand new user
$user = User::factory()->create();

//cookie
$cookie = ['affiliate', $affiliate->id];

$this->actingAs($user);
$this->disableCookieEncryption();

// Setting the cookie
$this->get($affiliate->referralLink)
     ->assertCookie(...$cookie);

//route where event will be dispatched
$this->call("GET", '...', [], $cookie);

//endpoint with user info, where user can check affiliateId
$this->get(...)
     ->assertJson(...);
```

Comment: Thx! But sorry I forgot to mention, that I'm developing a Laravel package and not an app. 

That means I have the issue: `//route where event will be dispatched` I don't have a route. Only the user has it.

Besides that. I just want to test the listener, like here (https://laravelpackage.com/10-events-and-listeners.html#testing-the-listener).

And there will be no `//endpoint with user info, where user can check affiliateId`

Comment: Than you cannot using $this->get in any way - you can only write unit tets.

Comment: But my package is adding a controller and has an own RouteServiceProvider. Very similar to this package: https://github.com/keithbrink/affiliates-spark